# ffmpeg get stream / codec information and use it to convert another file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two video files:
example.mp4 and output.mp4.

I want to convert output.mp4 to the exact codec, bt7, Major / minor brand etc as example.mp4.

I know I can extract that data with ffmpeg or exiftool, but is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
  final FlutterFFprobe _flutterFFProbe = FlutterFFprobe();
  MediaInformation mi = await _flutterFFProbe.getMediaInformation(FileUrl);
  Map<dynamic, dynamic>? mediaProperties = mi.getMediaProperties();
  Map<dynamic, dynamic>? allProperties = mi.getAllProperties();
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but what language is this? And if I read it correctly, it only reads the info now, but does not use it on the new file?